# CSS aligning form elements

Tags: css, forms, flexbox, alignment, element

I am trying to turn this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

Here is my html code:

```
<main class="container">
    <section class="new-tweet">
        <h2>Compose Tweet</h2>
        <form method="POST" action="/tweets">
            <textarea name="text" placeholder="What are you humming about?"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Tweet">
            <span class="counter">140</span>
        </form>
    </section>
</main>
```

And here is my CSS

```
.new-tweet {
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
    background-color: #ececec;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: #bdbdbd;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.new-tweet h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
    border-bottom: solid #4a4747 2.2px;
}

.new-tweet input {
     width: 100px;
     float: left;
     padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

It looks like this is something that a grid would be useful for but any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, correct the HTML and add a div to include the `<input>` and `<span>` at the form.

```
<div class="inside">            
    <input value="Tweet" type="submit"> 
    <span class="counter">140</span>
</div>
```

After that, write this in the CSS:

```
.form {
display:contents;
}

span {
margin-top:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I manually changed the width. It's all good now.